# Worldwide High-Resolution Water Body Shapefiles with Consistent Scale

Tags: shapefile, data, scale, resolution, accuracy

Where from your website can I access worldwide vector water body shapefiles that have better resolution than the generic SRTM 90m data?

Do you have coastlines and inland features (lakes, estuaries, reservoirs, and rivers) which are better than SRTM and that the scale is consistent across the entire coastline?

Also, is your data surveyed, generated from an open source mapping team, or is it gathered from other sources such as the USGS, Geoscience Australia, etc?

If your data is gathered and collected, do you have published metadata associated per set?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As it stands I think your question is too broad for our focussed Q&A format.  If you take the [Tour] you will see that we think one question per question works best here.  I recommend that you edit your question to perhaps focus on just asking "Where to find worldwide vector water body shapefiles that have better resolution than generic SRTM 90m data?" first.  At the same time be sure to research before asking because I suspect that this (or something similar) may have been asked here before.

Answer (score 2):

As PolyGo and Brad noted, StackExchange does not host data itself. For a global dataset of inland waterways, SRTM may be the best source readily available. Have you looked at a description of the [data. It is actually quite good resolution considering the extent.](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/srtm_water_body_dataset)

If you are interested in coastlines and will be working at various scales I also recommend checking out the 
Global Self-consistent, Hierarchical, High-resolution Geography Database, which uses various input data sources.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer the exact question you asked. If that isn't what you really meant, please update your question.

> Where from your website can I access worldwide vector water body
>   shapefiles that have better resolution than the generic SRTM 90m data?

You can't. This website (gis.stackexchange.com) is a Q&A site (per PolyGeo's comment on your question). It isn't a source of data, its a source of answers.

> Do you have coastlines and inland features (lakes, estuaries,
>   reservoirs, and rivers) which are better than SRTM and that the scale
>   is consistent across the entire coastline?

This website does not. See first answer.

> Also, is your data surveyed, generated from an open source mapping
>   team, or is it gathered from other sources such as the USGS,
>   Geoscience Australia, etc?

Not applicable, see first answer.

> If your data is gathered and collected, do you have published metadata
>   associated per set?

Not applicable, see first answer.

Perhaps it would help to show what you've already searched, starting with http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSMCoastline

Comment: I feel that this would be better as an comment, rather than an answer;

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: I originally did, but it was too long and confusing without the context. I'm planning to delete it if the question changes significantly.